# I need advice about params of opencv_traincascade for my training set

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have two datasets: first one is 340 images size of 440x200, on every image is objects of size between 9x10 px and 25x15 px. And I have a negative set about 570 images size of 440x200. 
I run training with these params: 
-numPos 250 -numNeg 22000 -w 10 -h 10 --numStages 24 --minHitRate 0.995 -maxFalseAlarm -maxDepth 20 -maxWeakCount 600 -mode ALL

I created my set from previosly marked up images.

I also tried -numPos 320 and 300. In first time it end with error "Unsufficient count of positive samples" on 4 stage(-numPos 320). I rerun training on same cascade with -numPos 300. It gives me another one stage and fall with same error.
In third time I choose -numPos 250 and it fall on 2 Stage and FalseAlarmRate in 1 Stage was 0! But in second stage 0.028.

So I will be glad to hear any advice about that, but my question is:
It is impossible to train cascade with these small set of positives samples? 
But it give me very small FalseAlarmRate even on first stages. So it can be a good classifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question:-

It is unclear exactly how many of each kind of image are needed actually. It also really depends on the object you wanna detect, how complicated is it exactly. It is possible though, let's take for instance, 40 positive samples and 600 negative samples is used in this website experiment, http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html.

However, the more complicated the object, I think you will need to train a lot more positive and negative image. If I remember correctly, a hand detection project I did about 3 to 4 years back, needed about 800 plus positive images and almost times 2 the negative images before my friends and I were satisfied with the detection rate.

Basically, the more images you train, the more accurate your object detection will be.

Your second question:

One thing you must note is  false alarm rate of the classifier is at least as important as the detection rate. Usually when the one-to-one false alarm rate is not strictly controlled, the overall classifier are unusable.

Also note that in most cases, false alarm error rate is greater than the detection error rate, making the false alarm rate a difficult criterion to minimise when designing a classifier.

Try understanding this via:- http://www.uic.edu/classes/idsc/ids572cna/Model%20evaluation.pdf
and another one easier to understand and learn how to train classifiers with more texts: 
http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html

So when you ask: "it give me very small FalseAlarmRate even on first stages. So it can be a good classifier?", my answer will be why not?

Also, if possible, try to increase your negative images to twice that of the positive images. It's what I always do.

Hope my answers my helped you. Good luck. If anything, feel free to comment.